# JTextArea pressing enter adds unnecessary new line

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener, key-bindings

I'm developing a chat application and when I press an enter button when focusing the JTextArea I want it to stop adding the unnecessary new line of text, so for example i will be able to determine when user has pressed the enter button and not typed anything inside the JTextArea. I am using a KeyListener for the means of detecting when an user has released the enter key and then sending the message. I firstly tried replacing the new line of text with an empty string message.replaceAll("[\n]", "") and also trimming the message, however it didn't work. Is there anything i'm doing wrong with my approach or would there be any other solution i could adapt?

Comment: Use JTextField instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Don't use a JTextArea for this, but instead use a JTextField.
- You can then easily listen for the enter press by giving the JTextField an ActionListener.
- Most Swing chat applications I've seen use two text components for this: a JTextArea to display incoming text and your sent text, and a JTextField to allow user input of the text to send.
- Usually one is right on top of the other using a BorderLayout.

  ---
- If you absolutely must use a JTextArea, then you will probably want to use Key Binding to capture the enter key and deal with it. Check out the [How to use Key Bindings Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

---

For example:

## **Example Key Bindings Solution:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CaptureTextAreaEnter extends JPanel {
   private static final int COLS = 30;
   private static final int VIEW_ROWS = 12;
   private static final int ENTER_ROWS = 4;
   private JTextArea chatViewArea = new JTextArea(VIEW_ROWS, COLS);
   private JTextArea chatEnterArea = new JTextArea(ENTER_ROWS, COLS);

   public CaptureTextAreaEnter() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(new JScrollPane(chatViewArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(new JScrollPane(chatEnterArea), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      chatViewArea.setFocusable(false);

      chatViewArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      chatEnterArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      chatViewArea.setLineWrap(true);
      chatEnterArea.setLineWrap(true);

      // start our set up of key bindings

      // to get the correct InputMap
      int condition = WHEN_FOCUSED;  
      // get our maps for binding from the chatEnterArea JTextArea
      InputMap inputMap = chatEnterArea.getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = chatEnterArea.getActionMap();

      // the key stroke we want to capture
      KeyStroke enterStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);

      // tell input map that we are handling the enter key
      inputMap.put(enterStroke, enterStroke.toString());

      // tell action map just how we want to handle the enter key
      actionMap.put(enterStroke.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String text = chatEnterArea.getText();
            chatEnterArea.setText("");
            chatViewArea.append(text + "\n");

            // *** you will want to send text to your 
            // *** PrintStream to the chat server here 
         }
      });
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      CaptureTextAreaEnter mainPanel = new CaptureTextAreaEnter();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("CaptureTextAreaEnter");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, however I already noticed that the JTextField will not allow for line wrapping how would I get this functionality back in a text field?

Comment: I would really like to keep the scroll to be vertical + line wrapped, otherwise if it's impossible I might be seeking for a solution to the JTextArea

Comment: Perfect, it works with the JTextArea via the means of setting custom key binding. Thanks :) For anybody with same problem this was a good resource to look at as well http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/245148-java-key-binding-tutorial-and-demo-program/

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that functioning perfectly for my system.

```
AddTxtA.getDocument().putProperty("filterNewlines", Boolean.TRUE);
```

**When user press on the "Enter" button in the JTextArea, a blank space will be input instead of new line. Below shown the sample output for two different situations.

> 1) Without  *AddTxtA.getDocument().putProperty("filterNewlines", Boolean.TRUE)*;.
>
> ***OUTPUT:***  "My name
>
> is Adam."
>
> 2) With   *AddTxtA.getDocument().putProperty("filterNewlines", Boolean.TRUE);*.
>
> ***OUTPUT:***  "My name is Adam."

Answer (score -1):

To replace the standard behaviour of "enter" key you should use the Input/Action maps of your text area

See the method `registerKeyboardAction(ActionListener anAction,String aCommand,KeyStroke aKeyStroke,int aCondition)`. As action listener you should take the Action from your "send" button, command is a string your choise, key-stroke is `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)` and condition is `JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED`.

Comment: I disagree with your recommendation to see the `registerKeyboardAction` method. Per the [JComponent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html): `"This method is now obsolete, please use a combination of getActionMap() and getInputMap() for similiar behavior."` Better again to use standard Key Bindings as per my answer.

Comment: Why? This method uses the Input/Action map internally.

Comment: The method is probably on its way to becoming deprecated. As to why, I have no idea. You will want to discuss this with the developers and maintainers of Java and Swing. They are the folks who put this comment in the Java API, not me.

Comment: As I know, this method is obsolete since Java 1.3. So I think we can use it next 10 years without to get a deprecation warning ;)

Comment: If you prefer to use obsolete and deprecated methods in your code, then fine, so be it, but it is not a good idea to recommend that others do this as an answer in SO, especially when non-obsolete and non-deprecated methods exist.